# How to reduce resultset in MySql query

Tags: mysql

I'm running the query below to create a crosstab from two tables:

```
SELECT vals.element_id AS order_id, 
IF( labs.label = "Gender", vals.value, 0 ) AS `Gender`, 
IF( labs.label = "Date of Birth", vals.value, 0 ) AS `Date of Birth`
FROM uc_extra_fields_values vals, uc_extra_fields labs
WHERE labs.field_id = vals.field_id
AND vals.element_id
IN ( 1022, 1023, 1024, 1074 )
```

This returns the result below:

```
order_id Gender DOB

1022    female  0
1022    0   4/02/2002
1022    0   0
1022    0   0
1022    0   0
1022    0   0
1023    female  0
1023    0   15/08/2002
1023    0   0
1023    0   0
1023    0   0
1023    0   0
1024    male    0
1024    0   17/11/1999
...
```

How do I reduce the resultset so it looks like this:

```
order_id Gender DOB

1022    female  4/02/2002
1023    female  15/08/2002
1024    male    17/11/1999
```

I tried a 'GROUP BY order_id' clause, but that just returned:

```
order_id Gender Date of Birth
1022    female  0
1023    female  0
1024    male    0
1074    male    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a hand

```
SELECT
    vals.element_id AS order_id,
    labs_gender.value AS `Gender`,
    labs_dob.value AS `Date of Birth`,

FROM uc_extra_fields_values AS vals

INNER JOIN uc_extra_fields AS labs_gender
ON labs_gender.field_id = vals.field_id
AND labs_gender.label = 'Gender'

INNER JOIN uc_extra_fields AS labs_dob
ON labs_dobs.field_id = vals.field_id
AND labs_dob.label = 'Date of Birth'

WHERE vals.element_id IN ( 1022, 1023, 1024, 1074 )
```

As a note, if each row of vals has precisely 1 DoB and precisely 1 Gender, then it would have been more sensible to structure in a way that reflects that i.e. a simple table

For performance reasons it may be advidsable to have a key on uc_extra_fields with the columns (field_id,label) as it would aid the join

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the following query to return the correct result:

```
SELECT order_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE field_id WHEN 1 THEN value END) AS gender,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE field_id WHEN 2 THEN value END) AS dob
FROM
(SELECT 
    vals.element_id AS order_id,
    vals.value,
    labs.label,
    labs.field_id
FROM uc_extra_fields_values vals, uc_extra_fields labs
WHERE labs.field_id = vals.field_id
AND vals.element_id IN ( 1022, 1023, 1024, 1074 )) AS ex_fields
GROUP BY order_id
```

The inner query returns:

```
1022    female          Gender                      1
1022    04/02/2002      Date of Birth               2
```

And the outer query pivots the table to return:

```
order_id    gender  dob
1022        female  04/02/2002
1023        female  15/08/2002
1024        male    17/11/1999
1074        male    27/08/1973
```

Comment: Did you give my suggestion a try?  Your suggestion will function however is liable to be far less efficient in the long run as you are selecting all fields for those users when you are only actually interested in 2.  You are also using an unnecessary GROUP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion and messed around with the query but couldn't quite get the information I needed. This query will only be run intermittently by the website admin. The tables are provided by a contributed Drupal module (uc_extra_fields) so I can't alter the tables without alot of extra work, unfortunately...